# calling vuex mutation inside filereader onload in component created does not mutate state

Tags: vue.js, cordova, vuex, quasar

I am building an app using vue and cordova (the quasar framework). What I am trying to do is, when user log in, write the refresh token in local file system using cordova-file-plugin, so the next time when the app is loaded, get the refresh token from filesystem then send it to server to determine if the use needs to log in again or not. But I failed the first step by trying to load the refresh token from file to vuex.

App.vue created:

```
 function errorCallback (error) {
      alert('Error: ' + error.code)
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
      fs.root.getFile('refreshToken.txt', { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
          const reader = new FileReader()
          const self = this
          reader.onload = function () {
            alert(reader.result)
            // self.$store.commit('updateRefreshToken', reader.result)
          }
          reader.readAsText(file)
        })
      }, errorCallback)
    }, errorCallback)
```

mutation.js

```
export const updateRefreshToken = (state, payload) => {
  state.tokens.refreshToken = payload.refreshToken
}
```

this is how i write the refresh token in to files system:

```
cordovaFSWrite (refreshToken) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
    fs.root.getFile('refreshToken.txt', { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
      const dataObj = new Blob([refreshToken], { type: 'text/plain' })
      fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
        fileWriter.onwrite = function () {
          console.log('Successful file read...')
        }
        fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
          console.log('Failed file read: ' + e.toString())
        }
        fileWriter.write(dataObj)
      })
    }, function onErrorCreateFile (error) {
      console.log('File created failed')
      console.log(error)
    })
  }, function onErrorLoadFs (error) {
    console.log('file system loaded successfully.')
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```

I know writing refresh token into txt file with cleartext is a bad practice bad for now I want to figure out how to make it work then think of encryption later.

thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to use `onloadend` instead of `onload` on your `FileReader` [according to the docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#read-a-file-).

Comment: I just try it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunate, can you specify what errors you encounter?

Comment: there are no errors. it just doesn't change things in vuex state. if i put alert(reader.result) inside the reader.onload(onloadend also works) it did successfully read the file content and then alert it on iPhone. it must got something to do with reader.onload/reader.onloadend